# Laravel, how to redirect to other page if my views have errors(any types)?

Tags: php, laravel

The title says it all, but the problem is, i don't know how to catch errors in views. I have read other solutions in SO, but `try catch` is not recommended in views.

Assume the controller has no error whatsoever, lets say my views has undefined variables in xxx lines, and i wanted to redirect to other page immediately without the user realize.

How do I achieve this goal? I already tried searching for answer but does not really help at all.

Comment: Have you tried putting a try catch over the `view` function in your controller?

Comment: make sure your `$variable` was definded before using it. `@if(isset($variable)) test @else not defined @endif`

Comment: @Jerodev no, again, assume the controller has no errors but the views

Comment: @grappler please carefully read my question, doesn't matter what the error is, i would like to redirect to other page.

Comment: That sounds like overkill. Just make sure that everything you access in your view exists and is valid. It's _your_ view, _your_ data, you should know if/when something is set in your views.

Comment: What is your goal you want to achieve by redirecting to other page?

Comment: @Zendy to tell the user that the page that user wanted to view is currently in maintenance

Comment: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#configuration). If you switch your `APP_DEBUG` to false in `.env` it will show error page. Is this enough in this case?

Comment: @Zendy i tried switching it to `false`, it still throws the error page. My goal is, as long as there is an error occur, immediately send/redirect the page to other page so that the user will not getting pissed seeing error page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found some workaround for your case

First you need to create a file in `resources/views/errors/500.blade.php`

in that file you should put some javascript that redirect to url you want in `onLoad` event.

```
window.location = 'url/you/want'
```

and then you have to modify `report()` function in `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` to something like this

```
public function report(Exception $exception){
    abort(500);
    parent::report($exception);
}
```

Beware though. Once you do something like this, You controller will throw every unhandled exception and redirect to url you specified earlier in the blade file

PS: The view itself should not have any error in any cases. You have to make sure the controller return all the value the view needs instead of handling error in views.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use

```
header("Refresh:0; url=foo.php");
```

Where 0 is the time waited before actually redirecting. But since you stated for no one to even realize, this might be the solution for you.

Comment: i would like to use this, but how do i catch the errors? (any types of errors)

Comment: You could either go for `try catch` or handle all the exceptions manually.

Comment: is there any alternatives beside using try catch?